# Set label after return with limit

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
MATCH (n:User)
SET n: Influence
RETURN n
ORDER BY n.Followers DESC
LIMIT 10
```

This code will first set a new label for all the User nodes and then return the first 10. What i'm trying to do is to set a new label just for the 10 first returned nodes. but when i do that:

```
MATCH (n:User)
RETURN n
ORDER BY n.Followers DESC
LIMIT 10
SET n:Influence
```

I get the following error:

> RETURN can only be used at the end of the query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MATCH (n:User)
WITH n
ORDER BY n.Followers DESC
LIMIT 10
SET n:Influence
```

should work